# Django call HttpResponse view in Javascript file

Tags: django

I want to call a HttpResponse from a view in my main.js file, but I'm getting this error in the console `//localhost:8000/%7B%%20url%20'join_dpt'%20%%7D 404 (Not Found)`, everything was fine when I had all in a same index.html file but now I don't want to have the scrips in the index.html so I moved it to a main.js file.

This is how I'm calling the HttpResponse (I was doing the same in the index.html file and it was fine)

```
d3.json("{% url 'join_dpt' %}")
```

this is how my folders order:

```
-- django
  -- env
  -- app
  -- project
    -- urls.py
  -- static
    -- css
    -- js
      -- main.js
  -- templates
    -- index.html
```

and I have this in my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#new
STATICFILES_DIRS =(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'), 
)
```

any ideas on how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put django template variables into .js files. The script must be inline in the HTML template file.